# Distinguishing characteristics of the concept art industry?

Tags: education, concept-art

What distinguishing characteristics apply to the concept art industry that separate it from from other related fields of graphic art, design, and illustration?

What are the unique educational elements specifically well suited to this industry?

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't improve on the succinct [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concept_art). There is an active website devoted to the the subject [here](http://www.conceptart.org/).

Comment: @ Alan sir Nice blog you have.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you some light..

Before anything gets created, concepts have to be made so that they can finally become reality, 
concept art is a subgenre of illustration where the artwork is not intended to be a final product, but a step towards a larger final product. Typically, concept art is not as finished or polished as illustrations.

> the main difference
>   Concept comes first and than it move
>   to the original product with the help
>   of other graphic tools/software

As i design sites i have to think how to show navigation,page block, which elements to take place  and all so this thinking process is in short is a concept how differently you can attract other with unique 
 idea(concept)

Concept Art  involves talent, skill, dexterity and a visual eye.

[A great Discussion on Concept Art as Art?.](http://forums.cgsociety.org/archive/index.php/t-524679.html)

for this field  all you have to be good in **idea, concept, drawing,**

Check these links..Carefully your answer is there :

- What is [Concept art](http://studiobond.net/?page_id=1123)
- A short [Essay on concept art](http://www.henryflynt.org/aesthetics/conart.html)
- You can roll in such academy for
  proper base [Concept Design
  Academy](http://www.conceptdesignacad.com/)
- You can join [TAD.](http://www.theartdepartment.org/) to learn
  basics of this field
- see this blog for [Concept art
  Tutorials and how to's.](http://conceptartmasters.com/)

For more Please check [Concept art official site.](http://www.conceptart.org/?)

Good luck.

Hope this help you  a bit.......